# How to find below element ? . I need to click the Excel image

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Code tried:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".exportPointer").click();
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"//img[@src='/xyz/img/excel_export.png']").click();
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"./xyz/img/excel_export.png").click()
```

Html

```
<span onmousedown="UX.preventSelectionUntilMouseUp();" onclick="abcd_.vars.tables[0].toCsv([true]);">
  <img src="/xyz/img/excel_export.png" title="Export to Excel" class="exportPointer">
</span>
```

Comment: Please give a little bit more details https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `By.CSS_SELECTOR` you need to use it as a tuple

```
driver.find_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.exportPointer'));
```

The recommended way though is to use `find_element_by_*`

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.exportPointer')
```

Or by class

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('exportPointer')
```

*The second and third attempts are not valid `css_selector`, you used `xpath` syntax.